# Jquery Ajax not sending multiple data via post request

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to send an array or object back using jquery post request. I have multiple inputs with the same name like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/details",
        date:{
            number:$('input[name="number[]"]').val()
        })
```

However, even when I fill up the multiple inputs with the same name attribute `name="number[]"`, I only get one value at the nodejs backend.

Doesn't jquery automatically post all the values with the same attribute automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `val()` on a selector that has multiple elements is it will only return the first one

You could `map()` all the values to an array.

```
var numbers = $('input[name="number[]"]').map(function(){
  return this.value
}).get()

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/details",
    date:{
        number: numbers 
    })
```

in php `$_POST['number']` will be an array of the individul values

Comment: This works. Could you please tell me the purpose of `.get()` in the function above

Comment: Gets array out of jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

[`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is what you need here

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/details",
    date: $('input[name="number[]"]').serialize()
})
```